# How do i get power shell to show a few services from my servers and not them all

Tags: powershell

this is my code i want it to show a few services from my servers but it keeps showing all of them. i tried using -Name but power shell 7 keeps saying that doesn't exist please help

```
$offlineServices = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server.Name {Get-service [string]$server.Value | `
                    Where-Object{$_.status -eq 'Stopped'}}  ).Name
```

Answer (score 2):

`Get-Service` can be used directly against remote servers, like this:

```
Get-Service -Name $server.Value -ComputerName $server.Name | 
    Where-Object Status -eq 'Stopped'
```

If you want to stick with your original remoting technique, you need to use the using modifier:

```
$offlineServices = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server.Name -Script {Get-service $using:server.Value | 
                    Where-Object Status -eq 'Stopped'}).Name
```

> **NOTE**: you should also remove the backtick before `Where-Object` as it isn't needed and might cause you issue later when modifying/debugging the code.

Comment: hi that works :D how do you do error checking with that aswell?

Comment: Have a look here: [Everything you wanted to know about exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.2)